# JavaScript or NPM module that checks to see if two object's properties clash/collide

Tags: javascript, node.js

I often times use _.extend or _.defaults (the Underscore library) with two objects to do JS mixins. But sometimes I fear property collision on JS objects. Is there some module I can use to check this at runtime?

Comment: Probably not, but a quick loop over Object.keys(objA) looking for each key in Object.keys(objB) would likely do the job. http://jsfiddle.net/htznfguo/

Comment: Isn't JS style inheritance [Prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)? What you're doing is more like pillaging and settling :p

Comment: yeah, you're right @laggingreflex, I removed "inheritance" from the question and just using the term mixin

Comment: it would be cool if underscore had a function that did the mixin only if no properties collide otherwise throw an error, or whatever

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a module, but it's pretty quick to write yourself. Since you mentioned underscore:

```
function objectsCollide(objA, objB) {

    var keysA = _.allKeys(objA);
    var keysB = _.allKeys(objB);
    return _.intersection(keysA, keysB).length ? true : false;
}
```